# Does this website provide consistent translation into Wookiee?

Tags: star-wars, languages

I was wondering if the website [Wookie Translator](https://wookietranslator.com) has any logic behind it or if it’s just a guy smashing his face against a keyboard.

Comment: Those seem to be two different questions, though (the latter more specific of which is probably better directed at the creators of that website).

Comment: I don't think this Q is a duplicate, but the answer in the linked question does answer this question indirectly. Didn't there used to be a close reason of *"not enough research"*?

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd - I agree. The question isn't "is there a wookiee language", it's "is ***this site*** providing translation into wookiee"

Comment: -1 You don't appear to have made any attempt to establish the answer yourself, when even the most cursory tests would have shown that the answer was no. "give it the same word repeatedly, see what is does with random keyboard mashing, etc."

Comment: I want to believe that a guy smashing his face against a keyboard can get *"uughguughhhghghghhhgh"* as the same root word in translations of "cyanoacrylate", "bananas", and "toilet paper".

Answer (score 60):

We actually know several Wookiee words and phrases, courtesy of the [Star Wars: Absolutely Everything You Need to Know](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars%3A_Absolutely_Everything_You_Need_to_Know) factbook.

> **How to speak Shyriiwook**
>
> "WYAAAAAA!" = "Hello!"
> "AARRR WGH GGWAH" = "Jump to hyperspace"
> "ROOOARRGH UR ROO" = "I have a bad feeling about this"
> "WWWAH RRROOOAAAH WHA?" = "Want to play some holo-chess?"

Wookietranslator.com does **not** provide a translation service that is consistent with these phrases, nor does it provide a *consistent* translation period (coming up with different answers each time for the same phrases).

Comment: hey I have that book what page

Comment: @Z-man - It's page 63 in the updated edition and page 47 in the original edition.

Answer (score 29):

Seeing how typing "hello" doesn't give a consistent translation, I'd say 'no'.

Comment: I tested this and got the same phrase each time for "hello", even in incognito mode.

Comment: @Burgi Huh.  Same here - it does seem to be consistent for some words, though does not match the known translations for them.  I think it just picks random words for anything it doesn't know (which is most things), but it's not _entirely_ random.  I wonder how many words it actually _does_ give consistent answers for?  "Hello" is the only one I can find so far.

Comment: @Burgi I had some words that seemed to stay the same as well, but after around the seventh attempt, they all fell apart. "hello" was the worst for me though, and was never consistent.

Comment: "hello" gives me consistent results, but "Hello" doesn't. Just in case further evidence was needed.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery In other words, this "translator" is bogus

Answer (score 8):

The site is definitely not any sort of attempt at translation; writing the same word (“a”) twice got me different results both times.

According to [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/28840/102999), Shyriiwook is a set of phrases made for Wookiees to say but not a real language.